# Does Http Client check for ssl certificate expiration?

Tags: security, ssl, https, certificate, ssl-certificate

I want to call a url through https. In my trust store I have the certificate of web site, but it has been expired.

However when I call the website through my client, my connection get successful. Does this mean that by default http-client not check for the validity of certificate if I have added it to trust store? Do I have to check the validity of certificate manually?

Comment: No, but the underlying implementation of JSSE might. I believe that IBM's does and Oracle's doesn't.

Comment: If a certificate is  explicitly set as trusted (i.e. in the trust store) this trust decision by the user will not be questioned. That is no expiration and no revocation is checked and it is not check if the certificate chain fits.

Comment: Thanks, can you point me to a documentation or a code implementation of this which I can refer?

Comment: There is nothing in Javadoc or oracle pki documentation suggesting default TrustManagers are checking expirationDate of trustStore certificates. Other users have checked it http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/105637/does-trustmanager-pkix-or-rfc-3280-x-509-really-check-client-certificate-expir

Comment: Acually this check happens when key signed by a CA, this is only skipped for self signed certificates